# Is Window Phone have a function as Android Call back function? Or get the event from Browser Activity event?

Tags: windows-phone-7, callback

In Android, I can define schema in XML, so that while browser or SMS have this callback url, will automatically open the application.

```
<data android:scheme="http"      
      android:host="test.demo.com" />
```

I am wonder is Window Phone have same CallBack function work like Androids'?

I am thinking to develop a App with some part using webapp, but some parts using pure app.
While user logged in the application, there is a webapp page containing a website, if user click on a specific link in that webpage, such as `http://test.demo.com`, i hope the Window Phone application can get the callback url, so that i can start the pure app view on Window Phone App. (That pure app view is including in the same application, not opening the other application)

Comment: I doubt if its possible in WP7.

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened the webpage on the `WebBrowser` Control inside your app and the user clicks any link on that webpage then that link will open inside that control itself and wont launch any other app. This is what I have understood from your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have some misunderstanding on window phone, i think that is not a question anymore, thanks for you kindly response ^^